# Laravel returns 404 not found instead of my 403

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have implemented a custom middleware in my application. And I have found an issue.

It somehow does't reach the abort(403), but instead gives me this error:
"No query results for model [App\Models\Meeting]"

My goal is to redirect the user back if they're on a meeting page that doesn't exist/exists to another user.  But instead it doesn't redirect me, but sends me that error.

Here is my middleware:

```php
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userid = Auth::user()->id;
        $meetings = Meeting::where('user_id', $userid)->get();
        $url = $request->segment(4);
        $idArr = [];

        foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
            array_push($idArr, $meeting->id);
        }
        
        if (!in_array($url, $idArr)) {
            abort(403);
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

The url is just the id of the meeting, so that works fine.

For your info, it can reach the middleware, so it is connected/added properly. It just doesn't access the if code.

For what it's worth, here is my controller where I connect the middleware.

```php
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(CheckMeeting::class)->only('show');
    }
```

Can anyone explain or help me?  Thanks in advance.

edit:

These are my routes

```php
Route::apiResource('login', LoginController::class)->only(['index', 'store', 'show']);
Route::delete('logout', [LoginController::class, 'destroy']);
Route::apiResource('register', RegisterController::class)->only('store');
Route::apiResource('meeting', MeetingController::class)->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('keywords', [FileController::class, 'index']);
Route::apiResource('file', FileController::class)->middleware('auth:sanctum')->except(['index']);
Route::apiResource('userignoreword', IgnoreWordController::class)->only(['store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

the URL I use is: http://xxx/meeting/10
xxx is the placeholder as it is not relevant.

Comment: I haven't used laravel a lot, so this is more of an (semi-) educated guess: I think that you get a 404 as `Meetings::where(...)` doesn't find anything for the user and then `->get()` causes the error. (I could absolutlely be wrong though)

Comment: @LorenzHetterich, thank you for commenting. The meetings is not where the error is. I have debugged it and it definitely gets all meetings associated with an user.

Comment: since you are getting a 404, then the route is incorrect or another middleware gave you that response. share your route declaration, the url format that you used and any other custom middleware you are using on that route.

Comment: sure @N69S. I will edit my post, give me a minute

Comment: @N69S done! if you have other questions let me know

Comment: since it's a resource route, same as `Route::get('/meeting/{meetingId}',...)` the link with `10 xxx` as the meeting id will return a 404, remove those extra ' xxx' and leave only the ID `http://xxx/meeting/10`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `response` helper

```
return response(null,403)
```